# SCRIPT28: Out of stack space on IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am getting below error in IE

```
"SCRIPT28: Out of stack space 
jquery-1.7.1.min.js, line 2 character 22385."
```

My browser is IE 10. This error occurs in IE console after page loads completed. Seems like script is not loaded or issue with jquery or issue with browser.

**My Code :**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

**Error :**

```
SCRIPT28: Out of stack space 
jquery-1.7.1.min.js, line 2 character 22385
```

Comment: ofcourse there might be issue with your code. post some code what is going in your code, so that we can try to sort that out for you.

Comment: The error must be somewhere in _your code_. Trace the stack to find out, see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh968260(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hi,
If i comment my script tag then it shows no error in IE console

Comment: @minoykansara you should add your script in your post above.

Comment: @Jai : here is the script
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Why not search beforehand? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264523(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: @BikasVaibhav The MSDN　article refers to Visual Basic instead of Internet Explorer 10+, which use a different engine.  For example, I ran into this error when trying to pass too many parameters into a function, and it does not match any of the causes descriped in the article.